# How to configure node-fetch to use the company proxy?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am executing a standalone nodejs script (no web server involved) that needs to fetch result from a third party api. The program uses 'node-fetch' to do the fetch(url) and I run it using `node .\test.js` from command line.

It fails when I am connected to our company network but works fine on direct internet. I have configured the proxy settings in npm and could see that `npm config ls` shows the correct values for proxy and https-proxy.

So the questions are:
1. Does running the test.js via node not pick the proxy config from npm?
2. How to make sure that the `fetch(url)` call goes through our proxy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked for me, try using this :
https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy-agents

The request formed will be similar to this:

```
fetch('accessUrl', {agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('proxyHost:proxyPort')})
    .then(function (res) {
    })
```

Comment: and what if authentication?

Comment: @PeterPalmer for me this works if you need authetication http://username:password@proxy.com:8080; this format is normally used even when doing it from curl for example